# RadGrid In-Line Editing with Hierarchical DropDownLists

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, inline-editing

Has anybody seen a demo or forum post that might help me out with this issue?

What I'm looking to do is to have a RadGrid with in-line editing.  I have three columns, "Category", "Question", and "Answer", which I'd like to use drop down lists for.

However, what I'm looking to do is when a "Category" is selected, to repopulate the drop down list of "Questions".  Also, when a "Question" is selected, I'd want to repopulate the drop down for "Answers"

I checked out the demo here:  [Grid / Automatic Operations](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx) and this is close to what I'm looking for, however it does not have the hierarchical drop downs.

Any ideas/comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example found here [Rows - Accessing Cells and Rows](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/accessingcellsandrows/defaultcs.aspx) should provide you with the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

On the first drop down lists Changed event (enable auto post back) cast the GridItem from the sender object's (the first drop downlist) parent.

Then once you have the griditem, do cast the second drop down list via gridItem.FindControl and work from there.

I dont have VS infront of me so not the most concise answer, sorry.

Edit - it could be cleaner and easier to extend to use a custom control in the grid, RadGrid is great for this.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Let me try it out and get back to you.